# PhpStorm looks for Google Chrome when I set up Firefox

Tags: browser, phpstorm, webstorm

PhpStorm 2021.2.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. I set up a Run Configuration as follow:

[image]

[image]

But when I launch this Run Configuration I get:

[image]

I don't understand why it look for Google Chrome if I selected Firefox as a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly that is correct / no error here.

**JavaScript debug is done with Chrome-based browsers only** (has been like that for quite some time now).

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.2/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.2/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html

> Debugging of JavaScript code is **only** supported in Google Chrome and in other Chromium-based browsers.

**To debug JavaScript using Firefox** you need to use **Firefox Remote** type of Run/Debug Configuration (need to manually create and use it) and enable Remote Debugging in Firefox in advance. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.1/debugging-javascript-in-firefox.html has all the info.

A ticket to watch after: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14987

---

**NOTE:** the aforementioned Firefox Remote type of Run/Debug Configuration **is no longer present in current 2021.2 version**. The last version that has it is 2021.1.

---

In addition to the above, from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010846880/comments/360003174860

> Unfortunately, there's nothing we can offer for debugging in Firefox now :(
> We used to support Firefox Remote Debugging (but without source maps) through the **Firefox Remote** run configuration, but our solution doesn't work in the latest Firefox versions due to changes in the protocol, and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to fix it. We've made some progress recently, but there are still some blocking issues.
>
> Related tickets:
>
> - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-45986
> - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48076
> - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2337